# Minimal technical requierements

Tags: federation

I'm looking for technical requirements asked for running in the same time on a web hosting service (if it's even possible) or a personnal set of computers :

- a federation server
- a custom-clone of StellarTerm client (if licence is ok ?)
- a custom-clone of Pricey (stellar-price.com)(if licence is ok ?)

I have a very little test-project in mind, and as an administrator of a little private web-community (+/- 100 members), i think i can learn a lot about technical aspects of Stellar using my members as volunteer guinea pigs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot speak to the specifics, but I have been able to get all this running on the [smallest DigitalOcean droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/). The specs of this server are:

[image]

So I would guess a personal set of computers is also capable.

Best of luck!